# How can I call the "Instantiate()" method right away instead of "Object.Instantiate()"?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: image showing code]
I found that `Instantiate()` is a static method.
how can we call `Instatiate()` without dot(.) operator instead of typing `Object.Instantiate()`?

For example, when we call `GetAxis()` which is a static method of the `Input` class, we type `Input.GetAxis()` but how can we just type only `Instantiate()` without the dot(.) operator?

Comment: If you are in a MonoBehaviour class, remove it. Done.

Comment: I have always typed `Instantiate()` without a dot, if its confusing, watch this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3u0x8VRJS4&ab_channel=Unity

Comment: Putting aside the case of `Instantiate()` being available separately, this sentence seems weird: "for example, when we call GetAxis() which is a static method of Input class, we type Input.GetAxis() but how can we just type only Instantiate() without dot(.) operator?". So if the same scenario is in another class, you're fine with it, but if it's in Object, it bothers you. Why is that? To me it seems like you're approaching the concept of static function calls all wrong, so my curiosity does not limit itself to your example of `Object.Instantiate()`.

Answer (score 0):

All Unity MonoBehavior scripts can access this method instantly without the dot operator. Just call it like this:

```
void MethodName(){
    Instantiate(<arguments>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate Function derive from MonoBehaviour.
If your class isn't inheriting from MonoBehaviour you have to call Object.Instantiate

E.g.

```
    public class YourScriptName //Note Here This Class is Not Inherting from MonoBehaviour
    {

    private GameObject gameObject;



    void RandomMethod()
    {

    Instantiate(gameObject); // This will not work since we are not inherting from MonoBehaviour

    Object.Instantiate(gameObject);



    }


}
```

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code. The text editor here has a formatted code block.

Answer (score 0):

The way you would do this outside of a class that inherits from `Object` is to import it into your file statically:

```
using static UnityEngine.Object;
class Foo
{
    void Foop()
    {
        Instantiate(null);
    }
}
```

Is identical to

```
class Foo
{
    void Foop()
    {
        Object.Instantiate(null);
    }
}
```

That being the case, it's not as clear as simply qualifying your static invocations as you call them, I can't really see any benefit to not simply typing `Object.` in cases where you are not a part of the Object inheritance hierarchy.